# what are the benifits of using Prism in WPF+MVVM application

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism-4

Please tell me what are the benifits of using Prism in WPF+MVVM application?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you read their documentation (which it would appear you have not), or [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785479.aspx) from MSDN magazine.  Basically Prism encourages and supports extreme modularity in your code: it allows you to dynamically load functionality from assemblies, helps build a composite user interface that each loaded component can contribute to, and generally adds a huge layer of complex flexibility to everything.

Personal opinion: for a small/medium sized application, I don't think it adds much; the complexity isn't worth it.  For a large, modular application that is deployed in a number of configurations, it'd be ideal for handling that.